# JBoss can't show war name while warning or error occurs

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jboss

I am facing problem in JBoss server. In this server more than 10 Applications are running and JBoss throws exception or warning.

How could I bifurcate which application (war) throws an error or warning. Is anything to show dynamically show war name along with warning/errors.

Below is the error where I am confused which application throws these errors.

```
11:11:19,361 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection] (http-web-1377112) Closing a statement you left open, please do your own housekeeping: java.lang.Throwable: STACKTRACE
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.registerStatement(WrappedConnection.java:1677)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedStatement.<init>(WrappedStatement.java:105)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.<init>(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:69)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedCallableStatement.<init>(WrappedCallableStatement.java:68)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk6.WrappedCallableStatementJDK6.<init>(WrappedCallableStatementJDK6.java:52)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk6.WrappedConnectionJDK6.wrapCallableStatement(WrappedConnectionJDK6.java:91)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.prepareCall(WrappedConnection.java:598)
    at ig.charging.SubsCommonBean.isSubscribedSp(SubsCommonBean.java:1114) [classes:]
    at org.apache.jsp.addconsent_jsp._jspService(addconsent_jsp.java:512)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:69) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:365) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:309) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:242) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:559) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:511) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.threads.SimpleDirectExecutor.execute(SimpleDirectExecutor.java:33)
    at org.jboss.threads.QueueExecutor.runTask(QueueExecutor.java:808)
    at org.jboss.threads.QueueExecutor.access$100(QueueExecutor.java:45)
    at org.jboss.threads.QueueExecutor$Worker.run(QueueExecutor.java:828)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not really opening or closing a connection in this instance. You are obtaining a shared connection via a datasource (connection pool). The **connection.close()** is merely returning the connection to the connection pool where some other component will pick up this open connection and use it for executing its own statements.

The whole point of having a connection pool is that opening and closing connections are actually expensive tasks (resources and time) so you don't really want to do this every time you want to access the datasource (usually a database).

However, this means that you should properly close a statement to force an execution.

This is a warning message. You don't need to explicitly close the statement but it means that it might not actually be executed at the time you expect. Hope that helps.

If you get this message it means you have track-statements enabled and you are not closing your ResultSet/Statements. This tracking is enabled by the following option on the datasource:

```
<track-statements>true</track-statements>
```

Comment: I Know this is an exception but I have to track in which application's throws Exception(Includes any War Name ). How could I track.?

Comment: Can you enable JCA Trace logging, recreate the issue and provide the complete server.log file so that we can better analyze the issue?
<logger category="com.arjuna">
                <level name="TRACE"/>
            </logger>

            <logger category="org.jboss.jca">
                <level name="TRACE"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="org.jboss.as.connector">
                <level name="TRACE"/>
            </logger>

Comment: I wanted the application name when exception occur. 
E.g. MyApplicationName.JSP/Java file etc.
Because in these server there are lot of application deployed.So I found difficullty which application throws errors.
E.g.  at ig.charging.SubsCommonBean.isSubscribedSp(SubsCommonBean.java:1151) [classes:]
 at org.apache.jsp.addDetails_jsp._jspService(addDetails_jsp.java:460)

Comment: You are not really opening or closing a connection in this instance. You are obtaining a shared connection via a datasource (connection pool). The connection.close() is merely returning the connection to the connection pool where some other component will pick up this open connection and use it for executing its own statements.

Comment: The whole point of having a connection pool is that opening and closing connections are actually expensive tasks (resources and time) so you don't really want to do this every time you want to access the datasource (usually a database).

However, this means that you should properly close a statement to force an execution.

Comment: This is a warning message. You don't need to explicitly close the statement but it means that it might not actually be executed at the time you expect. Hope that helps. A pooled connection close is only required at the end of the lifecycle of the pool, closing the underlying connection.  Check with your developer team and close the connections, statements, resultssets . See the java class: (SubsCommonBean.java:1114) from your trcae log

Comment: Yeah,It's true.But which applications this warning.How could I find out??

Comment: Check the method name: isSubscribedSp() - SubsCommonBean.class  @ line no 1114 : ig.charging.SubsCommonBean.isSubscribedSp(SubsCommonBean.java:1114) [classes:]

Answer (score 0):

War file name you find in server.log file. If you can enable JCA Trace logging to see your  application code stack trace :

```
<logger category="com.arjuna">
                <level name="TRACE"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="org.jboss.jca">
                <level name="TRACE"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="org.jboss.as.connector">
                <level name="TRACE"/>
            </logger>
```